# Digit amount in an integer

Tags: java, math

How can I find the amount of digits in an integer? Mathematically, and by using functions if there are any.

I don't really know how to do that, since I'm a somewhat beginner.

Comment: Mathematically it is floor(log10(abs(integer))) + 1 ...

Comment: well .. what did you try? On this site it's _required_ that to do some research before posting (the duplicate is one of many that came up in a quick search with a general purpose search engine). Please take the tour through the how-to-ask pages ..

Answer (score 0):

In Java, I would convert the integer to a string using the .toString() function and then use the string to determine the number of digits.

```
Integer digit = 10000;
Integer digitLength = abs(digit).toString().length();
```

Comment: Correct, I did not think of the sign, thanks. You may need to check the length of the absolute value instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to do it iteratively by dividing number by `10`, until result is `0`.

```
int number = ...;
int count = 1;
while ((number /= 10) != 0) {
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to calculate the number of digits in a number. The main difference between them is how important performance is to you. The first way is to translate a number into a string and then take its length:

```
public static int countDigitsFoo(int x) {
    if (x == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot invert Integer.MIN_VALUE");
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        return countDigitsFoo(-x); // + 1; if you want count '-'
    }
    return Integer.toString(x).length();
}
```

This method is bad for everyone, except that it is easy to write. Here there is an extra allocation of memory, namely the translation of a number into a string. That with private calls to this function will hit performance very hard.

The second way. You can use integer division and sort of go by the number from right to left:

```
public static int countDigitsBoo(int x) {
    if (x == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot invert Integer.MIN_VALUE");
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        return countDigitsBoo(-x); // + 1; if you want count '-'
    }

    int count = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        count++;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

but even this method can be improved. I will not write it in full, but I will give part of the code.
P.S. never use this method, it is rather another way to solve this problem, but no more

```
public static int countDigitsHoo(int x) {
    if (x == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot invert Integer.MIN_VALUE");
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        return countDigitsHoo(-x); // + 1; if you want count '-'
    }

    if (x < 10) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (x < 100) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (x < 1000) {
        return 3;
    }

    // ...

    return 10;
}
```

You also need to decide what is the number of digits in the number. Should I count the minus sign along with this? Also, in addition, you need to add a condition on Integer.MIN_VALUE because

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE == -Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

This is due to the fact that taking a unary minus occurs by -x = ~x + 1 at the hardware level, which leads to "looping" on -Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: Do you have any benchmarks to show the difference in performance between `ifs` and iterative division? Even if it faster, i can't imagine the performance increase being significant enough to justify writing large number `ifs` - what happens if the input might be a number with 100 digits for example.

Comment: You can simplify the negative checks using `Math.abs(x)` to get the absolute value.

Comment: @Chaosfire alas, I don't have benchmarks for this, I would probably say that of course a large number of conditions are unlikely to significantly improve performance. All I can argue is that the assembler division operation for the processor is more labor-intensive than the condition

Comment: I meant, that in the case of possibly large inputs, many `ifs` are required and it would not be justifiable from clean code point of view.

Comment: this would not be very much since int has a maximum number of two billion in which 10 digits, that is, it would take only ten if. Also, all the powers of ten can be entered into an array and run through them in a loop

Answer (score 0):

In this program we use a for loop without any body.

On each iteration, the value of num is divided by 10 and count is incremented by 1.

The for loop exits when num != 0 is false, i.e. num = 0.

Since, for loop doesn't have a body, you can change it to a single statement in Java as such:

for(; num != 0; num/=10, ++count);

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0, num = 123456;

    for (; num != 0; num /= 10, ++count) {
    }

    System.out.println("Number of digits: " + count);
  }
}
```